# Less resource intensive way of changing a lot of strings in array JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, mapping, sanitization

I'm trying to change a lot of strings and haven't found a "good" way.
What I want to do is remove some strings based on different criteria.
Exactly:

1. change 'PD-111 S/A' to 'PD-111' < remove all instances of 'S/A' when the string starts with 'PD-'
2. change 'KL.OTHERSTUFF' to 'KLOTHERSTUFF' < remove all instances of '.' when the string starts with 'KL'
3. change 'BD5000-50' to 'BD5000' < remove all instances of '-50' when the string starts with 'BD'

I've tried the .startsWith() and .replace() without any luck and diff iterators like .map to try to create a function to delete based on criteria.

I ended doing a forEach but it's incredibly resource intensive (since the total changes would be around 4k strings). It works but it's really bad I think eventhough I'm a pretty serious noob.

I'll do reproducible code next:

```js
let firstArr = [{
    sku: 'PD-123-A S/A',
    stock: '0'
  },
  {
    sku: 'PD-123-B S/A',
    stock: '1'
  },
  {
    sku: 'PD-123-C S/A',
    stock: '1'
  }
]

let repl = {
  'PD-123-A S/A': 'PD-123-A',
  'PD-123-B S/A': 'PD-123-B',
  'PD-123-C S/A': 'PD-123-C',
}

firstArr.forEach(element => {
  let keys = Object.keys(repl);
  let values = Object.values(repl);
  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (keys[i] === element.sku) {
      element.sku = values[i];
    }
  }
});
console.log(firstArr);
```

Comment: Iterating through `Object.keys(repl)` doesn't make sense. You should simplify to `for (const element of firstArr) if (element.sku in repl) element.sku = repl[element.sku];`

Comment: I don't get how your `repl` object, which holds individual match-and-replace pairs, could be used to implement the logic you describe ("*remove all instances of 'S/A' when the string starts with 'PD-', remove all instances of '.' when the string starts with 'KL', remove all instances of '-50' when the string starts with 'BD'*". `replace` **is** the right tool for that job. Can you show us how you tried to use it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most viable solution most probably would be based on a single re-usable mapper function which gets the regex lookup (key-value pairs of a string value's start sequence and its regex based replacement pattern) passed as the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method's optional 2nd [`thisArg` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters_in_detail).

The mapping function is implemented generically, thus agnostic to any item property. It operates all of an original item's [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), executes the replacement at just string type values and creates a sanitized shallow copy of the originally processed item. Thus the original data structure does not get mutated.

```js
function createSanitizedEntriesFromBoundRegMap(item) {
  const regMap = this;

  return Object
    .fromEntries(
      Object
        .entries(item)
        .map(([key, value]) => [
          key,
          // target string values only.
          ('string' === typeof value)
            ? value.replace(
                regMap[value.slice(0, 3)] ??
                regMap[value.slice(0, 2)] ??
                '', ''
              )
            : value
        ])
    );
}

const sampleArray = [{
  asu: 'BD5000-50',
  sku: 'PD-123-A S/A',
  tvz: 'KL.OTHERSTUFF',
  stock: '0',
}, {
  tvz: 'KL.EVE.R.STUFF',
  sku: 'PD-123-B S/A',
  stock: '1',
}, {
  sku: 'PD-123-C S/A',
  asu: 'BD300-5000-5000',
  stock: '1',
}];

const resultArray = sampleArray
  .map(createSanitizedEntriesFromBoundRegMap, {
    // provide the regex lookup as `thisArg`.
    'PD-': /\s*S\/A\s*/g,
    KL: /\.+/g,
    BD: /-50/g,
  });

console.log({
  resultArray,
  sampleArray,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

One of the above implementation's core features is the lookup based regex access which supports keys of varying length. The next provided test code demonstrates this solution's main idea.

```js
const regMap = {
  'PD-': /\s*S\/A\s*/g,
  KL: /\.+/g,
  BD: /-50/g,
};
const pdValue = 'PD-123-A S/A';
const klValue = 'KL.OTHERSTUFF';
const bdValue = 'BD5000-50';

console.log({
  regXSearch_pdTest:
    regMap[pdValue.slice(0, 3)] ?? regMap[pdValue.slice(0, 2)],
  regXSearch_klTest:
    regMap[klValue.slice(0, 3)] ?? regMap[klValue.slice(0, 2)],
  regXSearch_bdTest:
    regMap[bdValue.slice(0, 3)] ?? regMap[bdValue.slice(0, 2)],
  uncoveredSearch:
    regMap['uncovered'.slice(0, 3)] ?? regMap['uncovered'.slice(0, 2)] ?? '',
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

But in case the OP just wants to map over an existing simple structure like the provided one with only two known/fixated properties, the above generic solution can be boiled down into a much more efficient (*"less resource intensive"* with the OP's words) mapper implementation ...

```js
function createSanitizedItemFromBoundRegMap({ sku, stock }) {
  const regMap = this;
  return {
    sku: sku.replace(
      regMap[sku.slice(0, 3)] ??
      regMap[sku.slice(0, 2)] ??
      '', ''
    ),
    stock
  };
}

const sampleArray = [{
  sku: 'BD5000-50', stock: '0',
}, {
  sku: 'PD-123-A S/A', stock: '0',
}, {
  sku: 'KL.OTHERSTUFF', stock: '0',
}, {
  sku: 'KL.EVE.R.STUFF', stock: '1',
}, {
  sku: 'PD-123-B S/A', stock: '1',
}, {
  sku: 'PD-123-C S/A', stock: '1',
}, {
  sku: 'BD300-5000-5000', stock: '1',
}];

const resultArray = sampleArray
  .map(createSanitizedItemFromBoundRegMap, {
    'PD-': /\s*S\/A\s*/g,
    KL: /\.+/g,
    BD: /-50/g,
  });

console.log({
  resultArray,
  sampleArray,
});

const firstArr = [{
  sku: 'PD-123-A S/A', stock: '0'
}, {
  sku: 'PD-123-B S/A', stock: '1'
}, {
  sku: 'PD-123-C S/A', stock: '2'
}, {
  sku: 'PD-123-D', stock: '3'
}, {
  sku: 'BD111-50', stock: '0'
}, {
  sku: 'BD222-50', stock: '1'
}, {
  sku: 'BD333-50', stock: '2'
}, {
  sku: 'BD444', stock: '3'
}, {
  sku: 'KL.111', stock: '0'
}, {
  sku: 'KL.222', stock: '1'
}, {
  sku: 'KL.333', stock: '2'
}, {
  sku: 'KL444', stock: '3'
}];

console.log({
  resultArray: firstArr
    .map(createSanitizedItemFromBoundRegMap, {
      'PD-': /\s*S\/A\s*/g,
      KL: /\.+/g,
      BD: /-50/g,
    }),
  firstArr,
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is good, the second part mostly, I would say a function was a bit much since there's finite usage.
I wouldn't only need to also be able to handle undefined's, since both sku and stock can possibly be undefined. I did it already with my "answer" just adding e.sku !== undefined iterating non-undefined skus and for the stock e.stock === undefined to stock: '0'.
I will mark it with this answer as I think it's the best option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much as of yet but I didn't try to use `.filter` and `.map` to do something similar, trying to go more the route of `.startsWith().replace()` but I can't really make it work.

While trying to reproduce what I couldn't do, I actually did it.
I'll still post with the answer and maybe hope there's a better way to do this.

**SOLVED**

```js
let firstArr = [{
    sku: 'PD-123-A S/A',
    stock: '0'
  },
  {
    sku: 'PD-123-B S/A',
    stock: '1'
  },
  {
    sku: 'PD-123-C S/A',
    stock: '2'
  },
  {
    sku: 'PD-123-D',
    stock: '3'
  },
  {
    sku: 'BD111-50',
    stock: '0'
  },
  {
    sku: 'BD222-50',
    stock: '1'
  },
  {
    sku: 'BD333-50',
    stock: '2'
  },
  {
    sku: 'BD444',
    stock: '3'
  },
  {
    sku: 'KL.111',
    stock: '0'
  },
  {
    sku: 'KL.222',
    stock: '1'
  },
  {
    sku: 'KL.333',
    stock: '2'
  },
  {
    sku: 'KL444',
    stock: '3'
  }
]

let b = firstArr.map(e => {
  if (e.sku.startsWith('PD-')) {
    return ({
      sku: e.sku.replace('S/A','').trim(),
      stock: e.stock
    })
  } if (e.sku.startsWith('BD')){
    return ({
      sku: e.sku.replace('-50','').trim(),
      stock: e.stock
    })
  } if (e.sku.startsWith('KL')) {
    return ({
      sku: e.sku.replace('.','').trim(),
      stock: e.stock
    })
  } 
})

console.log(b)
```

Comment: you can achieve the same you have done here with forEach

Comment: Please provide some evidence that this is less resource intensive...

Comment: I'm using this to iterate over a google sheets I get through the sheets API. The sheet in question has over 95k rows and the original forEach hanged the browser and took roughly 1 to 2mins in a simple node app. This 'answer' makes it near instant.
I'm not sure resource intensive is the exact word as I've said I'm very new, but I figured if it hanged the browser + took 1 to 2 mins in node, it was a resource 'issue'.
In my flow I > get 95k row sheets throught the API > concurrently fetch roughly 30k products from another API > get the final array with the update values in around 3mins.